# How to Integrate HDIV and ExtJS

Tags: java, spring-mvc, extjs, hdiv

I'm using Spring MVC v3.1.0 and HDIV (HTTP Data Integrity Validator) v2.1.0 as server-side framework and ExtJS v4.0 as client-side framework.

Now, I'm confused how to generate secure forms and links which contains HDIV state
and how to transform/convert those forms using ExtJS on client-side.

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I'm confused how to generate secure forms and links which contains HDIV 
>   state and how to transform/convert those forms ....

Hdiv will do it for you if you configure spring to use hdiv.

See chapter `7.2.1.2 Modify the deployment descriptor in /WEB-INF/web.xml` of the [hdiv-reference.pdf](http://hdiv.org/docs/hdiv-reference.pdf)